# Ускорить поиск строк в массиве с длиной меньше средней

Tags: java, алгоритм

Выполнял задание: найти в массиве все строки, длина которых меньше средней длины всех строк. Получился алгоритм, работющий за линейное время:

```
public List<String> getLessMiddle(String[] src) {
    final List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    int common = 0;

    for (String s : src) {
        common += s.length();
    }

    final int middle = common / src.length;

    for (String s : src) {
        if (s.length() < middle) {
            result.add(s);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Можно ли сделать его быстрее?

Comment: Pavel, два прохода это не квадратичный алгоритм а o(n).

Comment: @gabba почему я же два раза по всем элементам прохожу..?

Comment: @Pavel И таки если у вас массив из 8 элементов, то будет 16 шагов, а не 64.

Comment: @Oleg я понял спасибо.

Comment: @Pavel, квадратичный, это когда у вас N элементов и вы по ним проходите N раз, то есть N * N = N², отсюда и "квадратичный"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сложность лучше линейной получить здесь не получится точно. Выполнить поиск быстрее чем за два прохода в общем случае тоже навряд ли удастся:

- Для того чтобы определить среднюю длину нужно хотя бы раз пройти по всем строкам и сложить их длины.
- Затем нужно вытащить строки с длиной меньше средней. В худшем случае (`n-1` одинаковых строк и одна чуть длиннее) таких строк будет `n-1` и для того чтобы их вытащить нужна будет хотя бы `n-1` операция.

Всего `2n-1`, что немногим лучше.

Возможно у этих строк есть какие-то свойство, неописанное в условии, например, неравномерное распределение длин. Возможно засчет этого свойства получится уложить строки в некую древовидную строку и производить отбор быстрее для среднего случая. Но выигрыш не будет значительным и если оптимизация алгоритма не является жизненно необходимой задачей, то не стоит усложнять код.

Т.к. по оптимизации алгоритма мне нечего сказать, перечислю проблематичные моменты по алгоритму/коду.

- **Ошибка при делении.** Используется целочисленное деление (`common / src.length;`) если `common` не делится нацело на `src.length`, то произойдет округление книзу. Это округление исключит при отборе строки, которые не должны быть исключены. Например: если на входе массив `{"a", "bb"}`, то средняя длина — 1,5. При этом строка `"a"` должна попадать в результат. Сейчас `middle` примет значение 1, и результат будет пуст.

  Чтобы исправить можно округлять кверху, либо использовать вещественный тип для `middle` либо решить неравенство и обойтись без деления вообще (в этом случае может понадобится `long`).
- Никак не обрабатывается случай, когда входной массив пуст (произойдет деление на ноль).
- Сумма длин строк может выходить за [рамки `int`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE), что приведет к переполнению и некорректным результатам.
- Переменную `result` можно перенести ближе к использованию:

  ```
  int common = 0;
  for (String s : src) {
      common += s.length();
  }  

  final int middle = common / src.length;
  final List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
  for (String s : src) {
      if (s.length() < middle) {
          result.add(s);
      }
  }
  return result;
  ```

Comment: Если самому написать quicksort и просто вернуть значение, по которому был разделен массив на верхнем уровне, то это уже n * log n

Comment: @etki да, что то подобное я и представлял себе, только сформулировать не смог. В любом случае хуже чем O(n)

Comment: я на самом деле видимо крепко ударился чем-то, сам по себе quicksort тут не поможет, партицировать можно в любом месте

Comment: Стоит упомянуть, что прежде чем оптимизировать, необходимо убедиться, что алгоритм корректный. К примеру: `{2,2,3}` -> `mean = 2.(3)` Ожидаемый результат: `{2,2}`, но что код в ответ возвращает?
 Для полноты, проверка на переполнение и деление на ноль не повредит.

Comment: @jfs про ошибки в коде с целочисленным делением («баг при делении») и с делением на ноль («входной массив пуст») написано в конце . Исправление их — тема для отдельного вопросаю. Подумаю как изложить яснее и написать про переполнение. Спасибо!

Comment: Верно, я вероятно невнимательно читал. Хотя суть комментария не о конкретной ошибке (баги везде есть), а об общем принципе: упомянуть для автора и будущих читателей  прямо в ответе: сперва следует убедиться что код работает (тесты), код понятный и читаемый, прежде чем приступать к оптимизации: ["make it work, make it right, make it fast"](http://wiki.c2.com/?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast). Я бы ещё добавил прежде чем оптимизировать, следует убедиться что код действительно медленный (измерить). Первое правило оптимизации: ["don't" (не оптимизируй)](http://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimization)

Comment: @jfs полностью согласен с Вами насчет преждевременной оптимизации. В данном вопросе автор напрямую попросил как можно ускорить алгоритм, поэтому и ответ в первую очередь об алгоритме, практические аспекты отошли на второй план. Подумаю о том как можно улучшить, спасибо.